# Конструктор переноса

Tags: c++

У меня есть задача: добавить в класс конструктор переноса. Память под поля класса выделять динамически. 
Я знаю что такое конструктор копирование, но конструктор переноса мне не знаком.

Comment: Нужно оформить вопрос, например: " скажите пожалуйста,  что за конструктор переноса или где прочитать про это?..."

Comment: Есть [перемещающий конструктор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

Comment: Концептуально, любой *конструктор копирования* является заодно и *конструктором переноса* :) Копирование - это наименее оптимальная версия переноса. То есть формально вы можете просто написать еще один конструктор с параметром типа `&&` и просто вызвать из него конструктор копирования - и вуаля: готов конструктор переноса :)